# Chrome Extension: Adding event listener not working after site loads

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm building a Chrome Extension to add some shortcut functionality to a site I regularly work with. I've tried calling my `addTypingListeners()` to bind the div with 2 inputs that I've added to the title and subtitle of the edit page I'm working on. However, I never seem to get into the `document.eventListener` closure.

My Chrome Extension is run at `document_idle` so the content should be loaded by the time my additional code runs. How can I get these listeners to embed on the page?

Even when I don't call `addTypingListeners()`, I still see `a` and `b` log in the console

```
function addTypingListeners() {
    console.log('a')
    var meta = {}

    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",()=>{
        console.log('listeners added pre')
        bind(meta, document.getElementsByTagName('title'), "title");
        bind(meta, document.getElementsByTagName('subtitle'), "subtitle");

        setInterval(()=>{document.getElementsByTagName('h3')[0].innerText=meta.title});
        setInterval(()=>{
            console.log(meta)
            document.getElementsByTagName('h4')[0].innerText = meta.subtitle
        });

        console.log('listeners added')
    })

    console.log('b')
}

const start = async function() {
    // var location = window.location.toString()
    let slug = window.location.toString().split("/")[4]
    let url = `https://example.org/${slug}?as=json`

    const _ = await fetch(url)
        .then(res => res.text())
        .then(text => {
                let obj = JSON.parse(text);
                const { payload } = obj;

                // Container
                const root = document.getElementById('container');
                var clippyContainer = document.createElement('div');
                createShell(clippyContainer, name);
                root.appendChild(clippyContainer);

                // Inputs
                const title = document.getElementsByTagName('h3')[0];
                const subtitle = document.getElementsByTagName('h4')[0];

                var inputDiv = document.createElement('div');
                inputDiv.id = "input-div";
                const titleInput = document.createElement('input');
                titleInput.id = "title"
                titleInput.value = title.innerText;
                inputDiv.appendChild(titleInput);

                const breaker = document.createElement("br")
                inputDiv.appendChild(breaker);

                const subtitleInput = document.createElement('input');
                subtitleInput.id = "subtitle"
                subtitleInput.value = subtitle.innerText;
                inputDiv.appendChild(subtitleInput);
                clippyContainer.appendChild(inputDiv);

                inputDiv.appendChild(breaker);

                // addTypingListeners() // tried here, also doesn't work
        });
}

start()
    .then( (_) => { 
        console.log('hi')
        addTypingListeners() 
        console.log("done")
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably the event `DOMContentLoaded` was already fired at the point of time when you set the listener. You can check that [document.readyState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/readyState) equals to `complete` and execute the function without subscribing to the event if it already occurred. In the opposite case if the `readyState` is `loading` or `interactive` you should set the listener as it is currently done in the attached example.

Answer (score 1):

1. The code you provided should be injected to the page as a content script (for [details](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#functionality)).
2. According to the [official](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#run_time) documentation, the order of events while a page is loading:

   `document_start` > `DOMContentLoaded` > `document_end` > `load` > `document_idle`.

   The difference between `load` and `DOMContentLoaded` events is explained [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/load_event) as

   > The **load** event is fired when the whole page has loaded, including all dependent resources such as stylesheets and images. This is in contrast to **DOMContentLoaded**, which is fired as soon as the page DOM has been loaded, without waiting for resources to finish loading.

   Thus, you should add the listeners without waiting for the `DOMContentLoaded` event, which will never fire.

Answer (score 0):

This is literally all the coded need besides whatever your doing to the dom.

Background.js

```
let slug = window.location.toString().split("/")[4]
let url = `https://example.org/${slug}?as=json`

fetch(url).then(res => res.text()).then((data) => {
  chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabId, {
    message: data
  });
})
```

Content.js

```
function addTypingListeners(data) {
  // Update page dom
}


chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((request, sender, sendResponse) => {
  if (request.message) {
    addTypingListeners(request.message);
  }
});
```